# How to sync vscode profiles?

Tags: vscode-extensions, profile

Basically, I've several profiles in vs-code, and I'd like to sync some extensions between them

Any idea how I can do that ?
thanks

I've tested several things:

- using the feature "Apply Extension to all Profiles". It's great, but using it, I still have to open 2 windows of vs-code (each with a different profile activated) and manually compare the extensions that are installed or enabled in both profiles
- exporting the profiles to 2 files and compare them with a comparison tool (using "beyond compare" for instance). The issue is that the exported text files are messy, not formatted and not easily readable, so the WHOLE files are different, even if 90% of the extensions are in both files. I've tried to format them with the "prettier" extension, but it fails to format the files (too much errors)

Comment: I don't get your problem: " It's great, but using it, I still have to open 2 windows of vs-code (each with a different profile activated) and manually compare the extensions that are installed or enabled in both profiles"
No, you don't "have to". You only "have to" if you don't trust the "apply extension to all profiles" does it right. If you don't trust that it works,you will not trust any other workflow except checking out the results.
But maybe i just don't get your problem right. If so, describe in more detail

Comment: that's not ideal, Each profile has more than 120 extensions installed !! 
I've done it manually , it took 15mn, not so long, but I just wonder if there was not a better way.

I trust the "apply extension to all profiles" but it does not solve my problem because I don't know what extensions are in each profile (even if the majority is on both). 
If one profile is C++ Dev and the other is Python Dev, some extensions are in both, but some are not, and I want to avoid unused extensions in a profile. That why comparing the profiles is the best thing I can do.

Comment: Maybe [partial profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_partial-profile) could be part of the solution.
I've not tested the behaviour. It would be great to have partial profiles so that you could inherit the extensions from the default profile, while adding new extensions would still be installed in the profile instance itself.
Profiles are still WIP a lot, so things may improve.
I actually sent an issue to (allow partial profiles being based on selectable profile](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193563) which would also help with your problem (I think)

Comment: thank @maddes8cht, this idea could be a good solution when starting from blank profiles. But in any case, the issue still persists if you want to quickly compare what extensions are installed/enabled in 2 existing profiles. Exporting to a file is a great starting point, BUT, I wonder why they made the result file so messy. It seems to be a Json file, but with no new line and some weird encoding for specials chars ( lots of "\\" for instance). Perhaps opening a ticket could be a good idea if nobody can give me a better solution than manually comparing 2 windows with different profile